# Center objects inside a RelativeLayout Inside Viewgroup

Tags: android, xml, text, view, centering

I have spent hours trying to fix a stupid and small error (from my point of view).
And its something like I cant center in a relative layout(inside a Viewgroup) 2 Textviews.
It's a Custom ViewGroup to be able to rotate the container.
I already checked a lot of other posts with problems similar to this one and not any of the solutions have worked.

I tried using gravity, alignText and all the combinations I found.
Hope that someone will see the error in the code!

Here is my XML:

```
  <com.android.ui.common.RotatableContainer
    android:id="@+id/preview_undo_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/module_indicator_height"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:padding="@dimen/content_padding_small"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:padding="@dimen/content_padding_small"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/undo_info_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="La foto se ha eliminado."
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/delete_undo_bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/content_margin_normal"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/undo_info_text"
            android:text="Deshacer"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.android.ui.common.RotatableContainer>
```

Here is the code of my CustomContainer:

```
 * Rotates first view in this layout by multiple of 90 mAngle.
 * <p/>
 * This layout is supposed to have only one view. Behaviour of the views after the first one
 * is not defined.
 * <p/>
 * Rotate angles can be only multiple of 90.
 * If mAngle is not multiple of 90 it will be reduced to the multiple of 90.
 * For example 89 will be reduced to 0, 91 will be reduced to 90.
 */
public class RotatableContainer extends ViewGroup {

    private int mAngle;

    private final Matrix mRotateMatrix = new Matrix();

    private final Rect mViewRectRotated = new Rect();

    private final RectF mTempRectF1 = new RectF();
    private final RectF mTempRectF2 = new RectF();

    private final float[] mViewTouchPoint = new float[2];
    private final float[] mChildTouchPoint = new float[2];

    private boolean mAngleChanged = true;

    public RotatableContainer(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public RotatableContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RotatableContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs);

        final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RotatableContainer);
        final int angleFromAttrs = a.getInt(R.styleable.RotatableContainer_angle, 0);
        mAngle = fixAngle(angleFromAttrs);
        a.recycle();

        setWillNotDraw(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final View view = getView();
        if (view != null) {
            if (Math.abs(mAngle % 180) == 90) {
                //noinspection SuspiciousNameCombination
                measureChild(view, heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
                setMeasuredDimension(
                        resolveSize(view.getMeasuredHeight(), widthMeasureSpec),
                        resolveSize(view.getMeasuredWidth(), heightMeasureSpec));
            } else {
                measureChild(view, widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                setMeasuredDimension(
                        resolveSize(view.getMeasuredWidth(), widthMeasureSpec),
                        resolveSize(view.getMeasuredHeight(), heightMeasureSpec));
            }
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        if (mAngleChanged || changed) {
            final RectF layoutRect = mTempRectF1;
            final RectF layoutRectRotated = mTempRectF2;
            layoutRect.set(0, 0, r - l, b - t);
            mRotateMatrix.setRotate(mAngle, layoutRect.centerX(), layoutRect.centerY());
            mRotateMatrix.mapRect(layoutRectRotated, layoutRect);
            layoutRectRotated.round(mViewRectRotated);
            mAngleChanged = false;
        }

        final View view = getView();
        if (view != null) {
            view.layout(mViewRectRotated.left, mViewRectRotated.top, mViewRectRotated.right, mViewRectRotated.bottom);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(-mAngle, getWidth() / 2f, getHeight() / 2f);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewParent invalidateChildInParent(int[] location, Rect dirty) {
        invalidate();
        return super.invalidateChildInParent(location, dirty);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mViewTouchPoint[0] = event.getX();
        mViewTouchPoint[1] = event.getY();

        mRotateMatrix.mapPoints(mChildTouchPoint, mViewTouchPoint);

        event.setLocation(mChildTouchPoint[0], mChildTouchPoint[1]);
        boolean result = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        event.setLocation(mViewTouchPoint[0], mViewTouchPoint[1]);

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns current mAngle of this layout
     */
    public int getAngle() {
        return mAngle;
    }

    /**
     * Sets current mAngle of this layout.
     * If mAngle is not multiple of 90 it will be reduced to the multiple of 90.
     * For example 89 will be reduced to 0, 91 will be reduced to 90.
     */
    public void setAngle(int mAngle) {
        int fixedAngle = fixAngle(mAngle);
        if (this.mAngle != fixedAngle) {
            this.mAngle = fixedAngle;
            mAngleChanged = true;
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns
     */
    public View getView() {
        if (getChildCount() > 0) {
            return getChildAt(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Takes any mAngle, makes it valid one for this view.
     * This means multiple of 90.
     */
    private static int fixAngle(int angle) {
        return (angle / 90) * 90;
    }

}
```

and my measure method for the View:

```
       public void positionUndoBarContainer(int orientation) {
        Size currentPreviewSize = CameraUtil.getPreviewSizeForAspectRatio(mContext, mAspectRatio);
        if (mUndoContainer.getAngle() != orientation)
            mUndoContainer.setAngle(orientation);

//       
        mUndoContainer.layout(getLeft(), getPreviewTop(), getLeft() + getWidth(), getPreviewTop() + currentPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Log.i(TAG, "measure" + mUndoContainer.getMeasuredHeight() + " normal" + mUndoContainer.getHeight());

        requestLayout();
    }
```

In vertical it looks like: [image]

And in Horizontal like this:[image]

As you can see the containers are correctly rotated and in the middle but the text inside is not, and I cant find the reason >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a *dummy* View (a bare `View`, 0dp wide and high) at the center of the RelativeLayout.

Then, for an **horizontal** alignment, align one TextView to the right of it and the other one to the left of it.
For a **vertical** alignment, align one TextView to the top of it and the other one to the bottom of it.

Comment: Hi mate! Good idea, but looks like its not working. The problem is not about position, is like if my relative layout its not getting the middle correctly. But in other way, the fullscreen is blue and the relative(red) is correctly in the middle of my Rotatable layout. 

But the when I center its always disordered, i dont know why

Comment: Also remove the `gravity` attribute. `is not getting the middle correctly` doesn't make much sense to me. Unless you aren't drawing the custom ViewGroup yourself - in which case there's some calculation error.

Comment: Give me one min, I will upload some photos. And yes, im drawing the View by myself. I will update the code now

Comment: I guess you need to provide the code for the custom ViewGroup, then.

Comment: Added Code and Images

Comment: Now, without analyzing the code, I found some more issues with the relative positioning of the TextViews. **1** - Rather than `wrap_content`, I would give them a fixed width, in dp. **2** - I would not set `toEndOf` the other TextView. **3** - I'd also use `match_parent` for the RelativeLayout's height

Comment: As a last resort, try using **2** different layouts. in `layout-port` and `layout-land`

Comment: What do you mean with two different layouts? One for each textview?

Comment: no, two **complete** layouts, with the same name, in two different folders. Google for providing different layouts for different orientations.

Comment: I will try it in that way, Thank you mate

Comment: Finally I just managed to position the texts with the onlayout() and onmeasure() method of my customview. Your answers help me a lot. thaks u so much!

Answer (score 0):

add `android:gravity="center`" in `RotatableContainer`

Comment: tried mate, its not centering the content of the Container